# OpenLayers - Add PNG image static from local disk?

Tags: openlayers, legend, png

I have some layers in GeoServer, where I used the OpenLayers technology to act as a viewer for these.
The code is the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>
    #mapa {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #control-capas {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      left: 30px;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px
    }
  </style>
  <title>Proyecto_Final</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mapa"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var vista = new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      center: [-71.55199, -33.015589],
      zoom: 15.5
    
    });

    var fuenteOSM = new ol.source.OSM();
    var fuenteWMS = new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/Proyecto_Final",
      params: { "LAYERS": "Proyecto_Final:Area_estudio,Proyecto_Final:Area_estudio_departamentos,Proyecto_Final:Puntos_de_encuentro,Proyecto_Final:Valparaiso_Tsunami_inundacion,Proyecto_Final:Vias_evacuacion"},
    });

    var capaOSM = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: fuenteOSM
    });
    var capaWMS = new ol.layer.Tile({
        opacity: 1,
        visible: true,
      source: fuenteWMS
    });

    var mapa = new ol.Map({                                                                                                                                                         
      target: "mapa",
      layers: [capaOSM, capaWMS],
      view: vista
    });
  
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to show a legend so that users who see the viewer know which layers are being shown.

For this, it occurred to me to upload a static image on the edge of the viewer. Over there I read add in .:

```
#legend {
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 40px;
         left: 5px;
         padding: 10px
     }
```

And later in  the following:

```
<div id="caption">
         <img src="file_address_on_local_disk"/>
     </div>
```

However, it doesn't work for me. The map goes black. So my question is, can I add a PNG as a static image in OpenLayers from the local disk? Because from a web file apparently I can.

Comment: What do you mean by "file on local disk"? Are you running your app from local disk? Are you getting any errors in the browser debugger console or network section? This problem has nothing with OpenLayers, it's pure HTML problem.

Comment: I'm new to WEB GIS programming, and I don't know how to associate a legend that I made myself from Geoserver to the OpenLayers viewer.

Comment: Put it somewhere on your web server and load it from there.